# paypal do not return txn_id in mobile site

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, mobile-website

I have using paypal in my desktop website and it worked. Below is my code:

```
<?php
......
echo '<form name="form1" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post"><div>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="'.$host.'/my-order-history">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="'.$host.'/payment-done?nid='.$node->nid.'&order='.date("YmdHis",$time).'">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="HKD">
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="'.date("YmdHis",$time).'">
<input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="0.00">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$paypal.'">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$total_amount.'">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.$company_name."-".date("YmdHis",$time).'">
<input id="go_pay" type="submit" name="next"  value="confirm" />
</form>';
......
?>
```

and in payment-done page, I can get the txn_id with $_POST["txn_id"]. But When I use above code in my mobile website, I can pay with paypal by I can't get the txn_id in payment-done page. What can I do to change the code to work in mobile site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Paypal says](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) the `txn_id` value is:

> The merchant's original transaction identification number for the payment from the buyer, against which the case was registered.

So this seems to imply that if you are not getting a `txn_id` value back from your transaction, then you're not supplying one to Paypal to use. So this means that you're loosing some data placement in your display flow for transitioning between desktop and mobile display of your website.